# Flutter: iphone app not running in simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, flutter, simulator

I am very stuck with this error, when i am make build of android it is working fine, but when i am running my app in IOS simulator, it is show me this error. i am unable to find out what is the actual problem in my code. please help me to figure out this situation.

my flutter sdk version is 1.22.4

> Running Xcode build...
> Xcode build done.                                           117.6s
> Failed to build iOS app
> Error output from Xcode build:
> ↳
> 2020-11-24 15:07:27.120 xcodebuild[84915:1186687] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOActivityCroppedImageProvider.h" is a
> member of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will
> be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the
> same path.
> 2020-11-24 15:07:27.120 xcodebuild[84915:1186687] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropOverlayView.h" is a member of
> multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be
> preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the
> same path.
> 2020-11-24 15:07:27.120 xcodebuild[84915:1186687] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOCroppedImageAttributes.h" is a
> member of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will
> be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the
> same path.
> 2020-11-24 15:07:27.120 xcodebuild[84915:1186687] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropScrollView.h" is a member of
> multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be
> preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the
> same path.
> 2020-11-24 15:07:27.120 xcodebuild[84915:1186687] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropToolbar.h" is a member of
> multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be
> preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the
> same path.
> 2020-11-24 15:07:27.120 xcodebuild[84915:1186687] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropView.h" is a member of multiple
> groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but
> membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
> 2020-11-24 15:07:27.120 xcodebuild[84915:1186687] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController.h" is a member of
> multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be
> preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the
> same path.
> 2020-11-24 15:07:27.120 xcodebuild[84915:1186687] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOCropViewControllerTransitioning.h"
> is a member of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups
> will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference
> to the same path.
> ** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:

> 1 warning generated.
> /Users/gajendrabhati/Library/Android/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.6.7+14/ios/Classes/FLTImagePickerPlugin.m:149:20: warning:
> 'UIAlertView' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert
> instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
> [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
> ^
> In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/gajendrabhati/mukesh/flutter/3Edge/ponde/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/image_picker/image_picker-prefix.pch:2:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Hea
> ders/UIAlertView.h:27:12: note: 'UIAlertView' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
> @interface UIAlertView : UIView
> ^
> 1 warning generated.
> /Users/gajendrabhati/Library/Android/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.6.7+14/ios/Classes/FLTImagePickerPhotoAssetUtil.m:17:44:
> warning: 'UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 11.0 - Will be removed in a future release, use PHPicker.
> [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
> NSURL *referenceURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
> ^
> In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/gajendrabhati/mukesh/flutter/3Edge/ponde/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/image_picker/image_picker-prefix.pch:2:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Hea
> ders/UIImagePickerController.h:62:51: note:   'UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
> UIKIT_EXTERN UIImagePickerControllerInfoKey const UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL API_DEPRECATED("Will be removed in a future release, use PHPicker.",
> ios(4.1, 11.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(tvos); // an NSURL that references an asset in the AssetsLibrary framework
> ^
> /Users/gajendrabhati/Library/Android/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.6.7+14/ios/Classes/FLTImagePickerPhotoAssetUtil.m:21:47:
> warning: 'fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:options:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 11 - Will be removed in a future release [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
> PHFetchResult<PHAsset *> *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[ referenceURL ]
> ^
> In module 'Photos' imported from
> /Users/gajendrabhati/Library/Android/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.6.7+14/ios/Classes/FLTImagePickerPhotoAssetUtil.h:6:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Photos.framework/He
> aders/PHAsset.h:74:1: note: 'fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:options:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
> + (PHFetchResult<PHAsset *> *)fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:(NSArray<NSURL *> *)assetURLs options:(nullable PHFetchOptions *)options API_DEPRECATED("Will be removed
> in a future release", ios(8, 11), tvos(8, 11)) API_UNAVAILABLE(macos);
> ^
> 2 warnings generated.
> /Users/gajendrabhati/Library/Android/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geocoder-0.2.1/ios/Classes/GeocoderPlugin.m:75:36: warning:
> 'addressDictionary' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 11.0 - Use @properties [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
> NSArray *lines = placemark.addressDictionary[@"FormattedAddressLines"];
> ^
> In module 'CoreLocation' imported from
> /Users/gajendrabhati/Library/Android/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geocoder-0.2.1/ios/Classes/GeocoderPlugin.h:3:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framew
> ork/Headers/CLPlacemark.h:73:63: note: 'addressDictionary' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
> @property (nonatomic, readonly, copy, nullable) NSDictionary *addressDictionary API_DEPRECATED("Use @properties", macos(10.8, 10.13), ios(5.0, 11.0), watchos(1.0,
> 4.0));
> ^
> 1 warning generated.
> /Users/gajendrabhati/Library/Android/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-3.0.1+5/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugi
> n.m:13:5: warning: 'UILocalNotification' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNNotificationRequest
> [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
> UILocalNotification *_launchNotification;
> ^
> In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/gajendrabhati/mukesh/flutter/3Edge/ponde/ios/Pods/Target Support
> Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Hea
> ders/UILocalNotification.h:18:12: note: 'UILocalNotification' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
> @interface UILocalNotification : NSObject<NSCopying, NSCoding>
> ^
> /Users/gajendrabhati/Library/Android/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-3.0.1+5/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugi
> n.m:295:4: warning: 'UILocalNotification' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNNotificationRequest
> [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
> - (UILocalNotification *)buildStandardUILocalNotification:(NSDictionary *)arguments {
> ^
> In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/gajendrabhati/mukesh/flutter/3Edge/ponde/ios/Pods/Target Support
> Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Hea
> ders/UILocalNotification.h:18:12: note: 'UILocalNotification' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
> @interface UILocalNotification : NSObject<NSCopying, NSCoding>
> ^

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Hea
ders/UIUserNotificationSettings.h:44:12: note: 'UIUserNotificationSettings' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
@interface UIUserNotificationSettings : NSObject  
           ^  
/Users/gajendrabhati/Library/Android/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-3.0.1+5/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugi
n.m:285:76: warning: 'UIUserNotificationSettings' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNNotificationSettings
[-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:notificationTypes categories:nil];  
                                                                           ^  
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/gajendrabhati/mukesh/flutter/3Edge/ponde/ios/Pods/Target Support
Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:  
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Hea
ders/UIUserNotificationSettings.h:44:12: note: 'UIUserNotificationSettings' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
@interface UIUserNotificationSettings : NSObject  
           ^  
/Users/gajendrabhati/Library/Android/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-3.0.1+5/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugi
n.m:286:44: warning: 'registerUserNotificationSettings:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's
-[UNUserNotificationCenter requestAuthorizationWithOptions:completionHandler:] and -[UNUserNotificationCenter setNotificationCategories:]
[-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];  
                                           ^  
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/gajendrabhati/mukesh/flutter/3Edge/ponde/ios/Pods/Target Support
Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Hea
ders/UIApplication.h:250:1: note: 'registerUserNotificationSettings:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
- (void)registerUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings API_DEPRECATED("Use UserNotifications Framework's
-[UNUserNotificationCenter requestAuthorizationWithOptions:completionHandler:] and -[UNUserNotificationCenter setNotificationCategories:]", ios(8.0, 10.0))
API_UNAVAILABLE(tvos);  
^  
/Users/gajendrabhati/Library/Android/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-3.0.1+5/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugi
n.m:296:5: warning: 'UILocalNotification' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNNotificationRequest
[-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];  
    ^  
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/gajendrabhati/mukesh/flutter/3Edge/ponde/ios/Pods/Target Support
Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Hea
ders/UILocalNotification.h:18:12: note: 'UILocalNotification' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
@interface UILocalNotification : NSObject<NSCopying, NSCoding>  
           ^  
/Users/gajendrabhati/Library/Android/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-3.0.1+5/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugi
n.m:296:63: warning: 'UILocalNotification' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNNotificationRequest
[-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];  
                                                              ^
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/gajendrabhati/mukesh/flutter/3Edge/ponde/ios/Pods/Target Support
Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Hea
ders/UILocalNotification.h:18:12: note: 'UILocalNotification' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
@interface UILocalNotification : NSObject<NSCopying, NSCoding>  
           ^  
/Users/gajendrabhati/Library/Android/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-3.0.1+5/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugi
n.m:335:34: warning: 'UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's +[UNNotificationSound
defaultSound] [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;  
                                 ^  
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/gajendrabhati/mukesh/flutter/3Edge/ponde/ios/Pods/Target Support
Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Hea
ders/UILocalNotification.h:62:30: note: 'UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName API_DEPRECATED("Use UserNotifications Framework's +[UNNotificationSound defaultSound]", ios(4.0,
10.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(tvos);  
                             ^  
/Users/gajendrabhati/Library/Android/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-3.0.1+5/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugi
n.m:351:9: warning: 'UILocalNotification' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNNotificationRequest
[-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        UILocalNotification * notification = [self buildStandardUILocalNotification:arguments];  
        ^  
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/gajendrabhati/mukesh/flutter/3Edge/ponde/ios/Pods/Target Support
Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Hea
ders/UIViewController.h:480:58: note: 'topLayoutGuide' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
@property(nonatomic,readonly,strong) id<UILayoutSupport> topLayoutGuide API_DEPRECATED("Use view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor instead of
topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor", ios(7.0,11.0), tvos(7.0,11.0));  
                                                         ^  
2 warnings generated.  
2 warnings generated.  
/Users/gajendrabhati/mukesh/flutter/3Edge/ponde/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:168:58: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first
deprecated in iOS 10.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    openedUserAgent = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:requestURL];  
                                                         ^~~~~~~  
                                                         openURL:options:completionHandler:  
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/gajendrabhati/mukesh/flutter/3Edge/ponde/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/AppAuth/AppAuth-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Hea
ders/UIApplication.h:123:1: note: 'openURL:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:", ios(2.0, 10.0)) NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");  
^  
1 warning generated.  
Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code  
Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code  
Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code  
Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code  
Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code   
Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code  
Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code  
/Users/gajendrabhati/mukesh/flutter/3Edge/ponde/ios/Pods/BraintreeDropIn/BraintreeDropIn/BTDropInController.m:418:67: error: 'topLayoutGuide' is deprecated: first
deprecated in iOS 11.0 - Use view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor instead of topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        return CGRectGetHeight(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds) - self.topLayoutGuide.length - self.bottomLayoutGuide.length;  
                                                                  ^  
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/gajendrabhati/mukesh/flutter/3Edge/ponde/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/BraintreeDropIn/BraintreeDropIn-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Hea
ders/UIViewController.h:480:58: note: 'topLayoutGuide' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
@property(nonatomic,readonly,strong) id<UILayoutSupport> topLayoutGuide API_DEPRECATED("Use view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor instead of
topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor", ios(7.0,11.0), tvos(7.0,11.0));
      /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Hea
ders/UIViewController.h:480:58: note: 'topLayoutGuide' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
@property(nonatomic,readonly,strong) id<UILayoutSupport> topLayoutGuide API_DEPRECATED("Use view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor instead of
topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor", ios(7.0,11.0), tvos(7.0,11.0));  
                                                         ^  
/Users/gajendrabhati/mukesh/flutter/3Edge/ponde/ios/Pods/BraintreeDropIn/BraintreeDropIn/BTDropInController.m:444:21: error: 'bottomLayoutGuide' is deprecated:
first deprecated in iOS 11.0 - Use view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor instead of bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        return self.bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor;  
                    ^  
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/gajendrabhati/mukesh/flutter/3Edge/ponde/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/BraintreeDropIn/BraintreeDropIn-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Hea
ders/UIViewController.h:481:58: note: 'bottomLayoutGuide' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
@property(nonatomic,readonly,strong) id<UILayoutSupport> bottomLayoutGuide API_DEPRECATED("Use view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor instead of
bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor", ios(7.0,11.0), tvos(7.0,11.0));  
                                                         ^  
4 errors generated.  
note: Using new build system  
note: Building targets in parallel  
note: Planning build  
note: Constructing build description  
warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
/Users/gajendrabhati/mukesh/flutter/3Edge/ponde/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOActivityCroppedImageProvider.h (in target
'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')  
warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
/Users/gajendrabhati/mukesh/flutter/3Edge/ponde/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropOverlayView.h (in target
'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')  
warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
/Users/gajendrabhati/mukesh/flutter/3Edge/ponde/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOCroppedImageAttributes.h (in target
'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')  
warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
/Users/gajendrabhati/mukesh/flutter/3Edge/ponde/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropScrollView.h (in target
'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')  
warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
/Users/gajendrabhati/mukesh/flutter/3Edge/ponde/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropToolbar.h (in target
'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')  
warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
/Users/gajendrabhati/mukesh/flutter/3Edge/ponde/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropView.h (in target
'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')  
warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
/Users/gajendrabhati/mukesh/flutter/3Edge/ponde/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController.h (in target
'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')  
warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
/Users/gajendrabhati/mukesh/flutter/3Edge/ponde/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOCropViewControllerTransitioning.h (in
target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')  
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99.
(in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.

Comment: It's hard to predict anything unless we know your project structure. However it seems like you have added `TOActivityCroppedImageProvider.h` at two separate groups in your project.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with your `podfile`, try removing the `podfile` & `podfile.lock` (move it elsewhere so you can move it back if needed), it will build itself again. I also wouldn't ignore all the deprecated warnings in your stead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had the opportunity to try building on a physical device?

Try changing the flutter channel and cleaning the project and pods. It usually works for me when I can't build for iOS.